# CakePHP 3: How to display associated data for each record in index.ctp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables `artists` and `pictures` with a `artist hasMany paintings` relation.

Instead of having a separate view.ctp for every artist that displays the related pictures.I just want to display everything in the index.ctp file all artists listed with each ones associated pictures (list of IDs).

After reading the cookbook and a bazillion threads I'm totally confused and don't understand how I have to do that. (I'm still very new to PHP and Cakephp)

In the `view( )` function for the single artist I can get the related pictures easily like this:

**Controller : ArtistsController.php**

```php
..
public function view($id=null)
{
   $artist = $this->Artists->get($id, [
      'contain' => ['Paintings']
   ])
...
}
```

And then get everything in the corresponding **view.ctp** by doing:

```php
view.ctp
<?php foreach ($artist->paintings as $paintings): ?>
<ul><li> <?= h($paintings->id) ?> </li></ul>
....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But how do I go about doing something similar for the **index.ctp** / index() function for each artist listed in the table? So I can essentially have sth like this:

```
<?php foreach ($artists as $artist): ?>
    <tr><td> <?= h($artist->name) ?> </td></tr>
    <tr><td> <?php foreach ($artist->paintings as $paintings): ?>
             <ul><li> <?= h($painting->id) ?> </li></ul>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know it's not really working like that but how would I go about doing it? 
Do I have to use a find() query in the Controllers index() function and store the results before retrieving it in the view?! I did try that but it either displayed nothing or it displayed an SQL query itself because I messed up the syntax somehow...

So after trying various things from the book and searching for hours it seems I am missing some basic understanding in my brain here. Also all similar questions I found lead me to nothing.

Even a hint where to start with this would be great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In view do you want to see data like as index ? or only want to see one user associative data ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean with that ;).
I want to see the normal index.ctp data (table of all artists) and additionally all paintings associated to every artist. So the associated data for all users in the table not just one

Comment: I mean do you want to see normal index.ctp data in view.ctp page ?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. I want to see associated data that is visible in view.ctp inside index.ctp:
In view.ctp for Artist Nr.1 it shows his data and a list of all his paintings (= associated data).
I want in index.ctp a list of ALL Artists and for each of them his list of paintings as list of IDs inside an additional column in this table. 

--> So one row of the table would look like this:
Artist ID, Artist name, Artist Surname, Artist Paintings
And inside it would look like: (1 | Bob | TheArtist | 1, 15, 26)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK It may I understood, I am giving you an example it may help you

There is `two table 1) artists 2) pictures`.

Artists has 2 fields `id,name`
And pictures has 3 fields `id,artist_id,picture`  // here artist_id has made a relation between artists  and pictures.

Here Artists has many relation with pictures, so we will write in `Model\Table\ArtistsTable.php`

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
 {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('artists');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('Pictures', [
            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id'
        ]);
 }
```

Then `Controller\ArtistsController.php` `index method` should like below code

```
public function index()
{
        $this->paginate =[
            'contain'   => ['Pictures']   //with artists We also fetch pictures
        ];
        $this->set('artists', $this->paginate($this->Artists));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['artists']);
}
```

Now in `Template\Artists\index.ctp` you can fetch data like below code

```
<?php foreach ($artists as $artist): ?>
    <?= h($artist->name) ?>  // fetch artists name from artists table 
  <?php foreach ($artist->pictures as $pictures): ?>  
    <?= h($pictures->picture) ?>  // fetch pictures according to artists 
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now you get the output like

```
jondu 1 2 3
```

Here jondu is a name and he has 3 pictures 1,2,3.

Comment: That's it!
The part with the paginate and contain inside the index method was what I was missing / not understanding. In the view instead of <?= h($pictures->picture) ?> I did <?= h($pictures->id) ?> since I needed the id numbers. Your explanation was extremely helpful to understand the connections! Thanks a bazillion! :D